# List all the release runs for a particular release definition in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to list all the releases (runs) for a "**particular release definition**" to generate release notes in Azure DevOps.

Example: Consider a release definition named "test" which deploys artifact named "apple" to dev, qa and prod environments for each run.

If the above "test" definition has run for 3 times, that is test-1, test-2 and test-3 then I want to list all of these runs using the release definition name -- "test" and then get the workitems and respective commits associated with each run.

Is there an Api/method that can list all runs for a release definition ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you gone through this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For listing the release of your specific release definition, you could use rest API like below:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/MyFirstProject/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=1&api-version=6.0
```

Find the `definitionId` from the URL of your release definition page.

Please take this example as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#for-a-release-definition